# Which is smaller storage: an identity primary key or a sequence primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Which is smaller storage: an identity primary key or a sequence primary key? An example of what I mean by sequence is below.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSeq
 AS INTEGER
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE Tab1
(tab1_ID INTEGER DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR TestSeq PRIMARY KEY,
 other_stuff VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);
```

*Bonus: Any recommended links for Sequence would also welcomed. I am trying to figure out there place vs Identity.*

Comment: Smaller meaning what, data size?

Comment: @ChrisShain Yes. Question edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as data size goes they are effectively identical (assuming that the type is the same).

The difference is that a sequence is separate from the table, and the numbers in it can be used to uniquely identify rows across multiple tables (occasionally useful) or used to generate unique numbers in a procedure without having to insert a row into a table at all.

Comment: Thanks. So is the data for the sequence actually stored or just kept in memory? Will it be lost if the instance is shut down / restarted.

Comment: Sequences are stored, yes. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx - "For an example, a new sequence is created with a starting value of 1 and a cache size of 15. When the first value is needed, values 1 through 15 are made available from memory. The last cached value (15) is written to the system tables on the disk. When all 15 numbers are used, the next request (for number 16) will cause the cache to be allocated again. The new last cached value (30) will be written to the system tables."

Comment: "After SQL Server restarts and a sequence number is needed, the starting number is read from the system tables (23). The cache amount of 15 numbers (23-38) is allocated to memory and the next non-cache number (39) is written to the system tables."